# carouFredSel breaking on fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, carousel, caroufredsel

I built an image slider using the carouFredSel plugin and everything works fine with one single carousel of images but as I continued building out my site I've reached some problems.

The first visible carousel works fine, but if you click the IMG link on the top right to see the second carousel, it neglects the bit of code telling it to only display one item at a time or something like that.

I've made sure everything is set up the same in both and I've tried experimenting with display and float changes with no luck

I'm also now realizing that it seems to be caused by the fading transition because the same thing happens on the first slider when I set a fade in to that as well.

Guessing it has something to do with the display change that the jQuery script does

```
$("#web-carousel").carouFredSel({
width: "100%",
height: 450,
direction: "right",
circular: true,
infinite: true,
items: {
    visible: 1,
    width: "variable",
    height: 400,
    width: 720
},
scroll: {
    duration: 1000,
    pauseOnHover: true
},
auto: {
    timeoutDuration: 9999,
    delay: 5000
},
prev: {
    button: "#web-left",
    key: "left"
},
next: {
    button: "#web-right",
    key: "right"
},
pagination: {
    container: "#web-pagination",
    keys: true
},
swipe: true,
mousewheel: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what's causing you trouble, but it sounds like it might be the same issue I ran into. I have my carousel in a hidden div revealed by an animate() triggered by a click. It wasn't rendering correctly until I put the carousel initialization into a post-animate function -- ensuring that the carousel wasn't initialized until the div was ready seemed to be the key, probably because the carousel code looks at the sizing of things when it's preparing the images. So what I did was to wrap the carousel initialization in a function:

```
var do_carousel = function() {
  $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    circular: false,
    etc...
```

Then in the code that reveals the div, it calls that function:

```
$("#carousel-div").animate({
  opacity: 'toggle',
  width: 'toggle',
}, 1200, function() {
  do_carousel();
});
```

Once I moved the carousel initialization there, it started working. I hope perhaps that will help you find the root of your issue.